# pants with isort thinks my python modules are third party

Tags: python, isort, pants

I have a pants project that I've modified from the [example repo](https://github.com/pantsbuild/example-python) so that the source code resides under `project1/src`:

```
├── BUILD
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── mypy.ini
├── pants.ci.toml
├── pants.toml
├── project1
│   └── src
│       ├── BUILD
│       ├── allthing.py
│       └── helloworld
│           ├── BUILD
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── greet
│           │   ├── BUILD
│           │   ├── __init__.py
│           │   ├── greeting.py
│           │   ├── greeting_test.py
│           │   └── translations.json
│           ├── main.py
│           └── translator
│               ├── BUILD
│               ├── __init__.py
│               ├── translator.py
│               └── translator_test.py
├── python-default.lock
└── requirements.txt
```

The `BUILD` files under `project1` are all boilerplate:

```
python_sources(
    name="lib",
)
```

I added the `allthing` module and modified `helloword.main` to import it:

```py
from colors import green

from allthing import Whatevs
from helloworld.greet.greeting import Greeter


def say_hello() -> None:
    greeting = Greeter().greet("Pantsbuild")
    print(green(greeting))
```

When I run `pants fmt ::` `isort` places the `allthing` import with the third-party modules:

```py
from allthing import Whatevs
from colors import green

from helloworld.greet.greeting import Greeter
```

I expect it to be organized with the other first party module, `helloworld`, as in the first snippet.

---

I modified `pants.toml` to reflect the sources root:

```ini
[source]
root_patterns = ["src"]
```

I confirmed that pants knows the roots:

```
$ pants roots
project1/src
```

This did not help.

The only way that I can get `pants fmt` to produce the correct result is to move the `src` directory out of `project1` into the root:

```
├── BUILD
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── mypy.ini
├── pants.ci.toml
├── pants.toml
├── project1
├── python-default.lock
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    ├── BUILD
    ├── allthing.py
    └── helloworld
        ...
```

With the `src` folder at the project root, `pants fmt` always produces the correct result, regardless of how I've configured the sources roots.

For the curious, `.isort.cfg` is the same as in the example project:

```ini
[settings]
# This is to make isort compatible with Black. See
# https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style.html#how-black-wraps-lines.
line_length=88
multi_line_output=3
include_trailing_comma=True
force_grid_wrap=0
use_parentheses=True

known_first_party=helloworld
default_section=THIRDPARTY
```

Comment: There's a long thread about this over in the pants GH repo: https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/issues/15069

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `src_paths` field in your `.isort.cfg`? E.g., add:

```
src_paths = ["project1/src"]
```

See docs here: https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#src-paths

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).